# Exporting Spring components as OSGi services

Tags: spring, service, osgi

Is it possible to automatically register a Spring `@Component` (or one of its specifications; e.g. `@Repository`) as an OSGi service? So I can use autowiring and all other benefits of Spring inside one bundle and OSGi Service Registry to communicate between bundles?

UPDATE: From [this discussion](http://karaf.922171.n3.nabble.com/Aries-and-Spring-Co-Existance-in-Karaf-td3438050.html) it doesn't seem to be possible using standard Blueprint, only in Eclipse Gemini.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you're familiar with [Eclipse Gemini Blueprint](http://www.eclipse.org/gemini/blueprint/) (formerly Spring Dynamic Modules, formerly Spring OSGi)?

You export your beans using the [`<service>`-tag](http://www.eclipse.org/gemini/blueprint/documentation/reference/1.0.0.RELEASE/html/service-registry.html#service-registry%3aexport). I'm not sure if you can export all `@Component` etc. annotated beans automatically though.

Comment: Ah, so if I _don't_ have `<bean>` tag, Blueprint will use the one created by Spring instead of trying to create its own copy. Is this right? Will this work with Apache Aries Blueprint the same way?

Comment: If you do `<service ref="beanToPublish" ..."` then that Spring bean must exist, either annotated (and named beanToPublish) or explicitly created with `<bean>`. I'm afraid I've never used Aries Blueprint.

Comment: and @artbristol just loves OSGi :)

Answer (score 1):

A possible implementation to support this without the hack @AlexeyRomanov suggested could be to add a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` implementation to the extender bundle of Gemini Blueprint via a fragment.

That processor than could create the needed OSGi export definitions inside the BeanFactory and it should work properly.

An example of how that could look like is the [`ServiceReferenceInjectionBeanPostProcessor`](http://static.springsource.org/osgi/docs/1.2.1/api/org/springframework/osgi/extensions/annotation/ServiceReferenceInjectionBeanPostProcessor.html) form SpringDM's/Gemini's extension that allows you to get OSGi-Services injected via the `@ServiceReference` annotation. (Although I linked Spring DM this class should still be present in Gemini, but I couldn't find a direct link to their javadoc)

Answer (score 0):

Nasty workaround, for singleton beans only: store the instance in a static field in the constructor, and use this field's getter as your Blueprint/iPOJO factory method.